# question about entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5, reference

i have such code

```
 var menu = _dataManager.Menu.Details(id);
        var menu2 = _dataManager.Menu.Details(id);

        menu.Name = "AAA";
```

in this case menu2.Name will be "AAA", i guess it because of reference, but how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity lazy loads data.  Force the load and disconnect it from the Model and then it will not be AAA.

Eager load:

```
DataLoadOptions op = new DataLoadOptions();
op.LoadWith<Details>(x => x.Menu);
//etc...
_dataManager.LoadOptions = op;
```

Update: It appears that in the past I disconnect by copying the data out to a non-entity POCO.

Comment: yeah, trying to find the code for the last time i did this.  reading any property should force the load.  Disconnecting is more specific.

Comment: Good answer Russell. It got me searching for a way to force an Enumeration on IEnumerable objects. I'm looking now but I dont think there's an Enumerate() method or anything. Would be nice in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `Details` method is set to return a single instance of the menu item regardless of how many times you put it into different variable names.

One solution would be to use a different dataManager object for the second menu item.